# how to get .net core default services collection in linqpad

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, linqpad

i create a azure function with .net 6 in visual studio and i use autofac for dependency injection and all works fine,
but when  i want to use some functions from the solution in linqpad i make reference to the dll files,
but i have some classes that have parameters in the constructor from IConfiguration and ILogger etc., that is by default added to service collection in .net, but when i use it from linqpad it's not in the collection, so i get a exception from autofac by resolving services

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'my class ' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
> Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration config' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration, System.Func`2[System.Boolean,RestSharp.RestRequest])'.

here is my linqpad code

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<RestApiRequsts>().As<IRestApiRequsts>().SingleInstance();
var scope = builder.Build();
var restapirequests = scope.Resolve<IRestApiRequsts>();
```

if anyone can help me to get the .net default services  in linqpad

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Your code snippet shows how you create an empty Autofac `ContainerBuilder` add just a single registration, and then expect it to magically contain all the other registrations? All those registrations do not magically appear in your application. They are all registered using dozens of extension methods that are being called. You will have to make sure those methods are called inyour LINQPad project as well.

Comment: i have a large amount of register functions from multiple classes,i just show 1 for the example